# Chrome extension v3 sandbox

Tags: service-worker, webassembly, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I have a chrome extension that was working on the manifest version 2 without a problem. I had some javascript in the background that included web assembly and required wasm-eval. I have converted the extension to manifest version 3, which doesn't allow wasm-eval or unsafe-eval any more. What I did for a solution is I created a new window (mainpage.html) from the extension and this window includes an iframe (sandbox.html) and this iframe includes the web assembly code and communicates with the background service worker with postMessages.

I am wondering if there is a solution without opening a new window for my case. Something that will run the sandbox.html running in the background and the service worker can communicate with it. I tried to put the sandbox.html to the service worker, but the service worker doesn't accept html files running inside.

Popup script is not a solution because the user needs to click the extension icon to make it running. Content script worked but if the website has a content security policy that doesn't allow unsafe-eval, then it won't work. I need a more general solution.

There is something explained here with the Event pages for which I have no idea, and I believe it is deprecated as well. Service worker cannot have access to the DOM. https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/sandboxingEval/

this is from the manifest.json

```
"sandbox": {
    "pages": ["sandbox.html"]
  }
```

this is what mainpage.html looks like

```
<iframe id="theFrame" src="sandbox.html" style="display: none;"></iframe>
    <script src="mainpage.js"></script>
```

this is what the sandbox.html looks like

```
    <script src="wasm_exec.js"></script>
    <script src="wasm_startup.js"></script>
    <script src="assign_result.js"></script>
    <script src="event_listener.js"></script>
```

Comment: There will be [chrome.offscreen](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/offscreen) API, currently it can be tested in Chrome Canary.

Comment: what does the sandbox pages in content security policy match to, is it something like if the visited page has a "page1.html" or is it like the extension has a "page1.html" somewhere running? https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/manifest/sandbox/ 
 I am very confused about the usage of the sandboxed page.

Comment: CSP of an extension applies only to its own pages i.e. chrome-extension://id/ URLs. It can be an iframe, too, e.g. inside the offscreen document.